# Using sed to substitute text around dynamic filename

Tags: bash, sed

I'm trying to figure out the best method for substituting text in a BASH script. Sed seems to be the best option, but correct me if I'm wrong.

What I'd like to do is take every instance of `images/< filename >.png` in a file, and add surrounding text - `{{media("images/.< filename >.png")}}`. The following code is the closest I've been able to get:

```
sed -i -e 's:images/.*.png:{{media("images/.*.png")}}:g' file.html
```

How can I make this happen?

Comment: Are there any constraints on the filenames you need to handle? Might they have spaces in them, for example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In sed, `&` in the substitution will be replaced with the matched string, so if we can assume no spaces in a filename and a word boundary before and after each, this does what you want:

```sed
s:\bimages/\S*\.png\b:{{media("&")}}:g
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY@xbsMwDER3fwWRoWgLK939Dd2Kbl5oiTAIiJIiUkGBIN/uqmrajQTu7t0phePQZd1YcCd9Wz9e13NJ@7ott5tQYHw@PZ1e7vdlP473XEmAizaBkGOuoGyAQjaDz0nJG1mr8MjCwIXVc9odRbaf2BmUQvdODwlxU8nBGUnJ1XHyHDi0NMTQDCJuHQpkv0CC7ksIGPnS8AyfBpRYJgwg3A@49hdlhktjhZTVagtAX1Q9GxrnBC1GFJ//Sg4Aq0us7NrgTiOdS/cBYV8mveK/YQzt8CH9Bg)

Apart from doing the substitution, there are a couple issues with your code worth mentioning:

1. `images/.*.png` will match `images/foo.png`, but it will also match `images/foopng`. Don't forget to escape regex characters: `images/.*\.png`.
2. sed quantifiers are always greedy. Suppose you had this input:

   ```
   Foo images/bar.png baz images/qux.png quux
   ```

   In this case, the expression `images/.*\.png` would match everything from the first `images` to the last `.png`. The solution above avoids this by using `\S` instead of `.` to match only non-whitespace characters.